# Etherscan API doesn't return internal transaction (although it has)

Tags: web3js, transactions, etherscan, web3.py

Here is transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x33e0dab83aa27ba8b2a08b3c69d61a34911a4adb6e7a35dd30cf11383f43fcc3 with simple Transfer() some GALA tokens.

Etherscan shows 1 internal transaction:
[image]

But it's empty on API https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&txhash=0x33e0dab83aa27ba8b2a08b3c69d61a34911a4adb6e7a35dd30cf11383f43fcc3

**1) Any ideas why it's empty?**

**2) Is there another options how I can get this data not using any API service?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because Etherescan is a private commercial product and only Etherscan support team can answer this question why their product works in a certain way.